# QGIS raster symbology not applying to the entire raster

Tags: raster, qgis

I am trying to change the symbology of a raster from "Singleband Gray" to "Paletted/Unique Values" so I can visualize the data better.  For some reason whenever I apply the render type the only thing I get is the top left corner fully changing and then it is speckled throughout the rest of the image.  In singleband grey and hillshade the entire raster is visible.  I have some images below.  Has anybody encounted this problem?  I am using the latest version of QGIS (v. 3.34.1).

[image]
[image]

The problem has persisted across all rasters that I upload.  I updated QGIS and still the problem exists.